# Magento 2: 404 for productpage image when click on swatch option

Tags: magento2, swatches

i have used the swatch option for configurable product and each of this color swatch product image
are different for that associate products. 
I have already assign different different image for this associate product base on color swatch

but now when i click on swatch option on product page then image is not change and its showing me 404 error for that image i have check the image in main image folder like ( catalog/product/d/e/dev.jpg)  and its available but it's not available on catalog/product/cache/0da44b14ba7470ad5b3ec133a23947b1/d/e/dev.jpg

I can not run this catalog:products:resize command every time so is there any other solution or any way.

Thanks.